# What causes the <!DOCTYPE html> tag and css code greyed in html but works perfectly fine if with the php extension? And is there anyway to fix it?

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code

Problem 1: I am using Visual Studio code as the IDE of my choice. When I use an html file and use the "html:5" autocomplete, it normally works. But recently it has stopped working with html files, however it works with php files only. I don't know if it's because I work with php files 80% of the times.

Problem 2:
With the html files the  tag and css code greyed in html but works perfectly fine if with the php extension

[HTML file, notice how the  tag and css code is greyed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0C98.png)

[Notice how in the php file,the  tag and css code is normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZR8H.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved the problem, the Django extension was conflicting between the types of html files (Django html or regular html). So I disabled the extension and it solved my problem.